# Why is there a variable feature in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

In SASS you are allowed to make variables. A variable provides a way to store and keep track of your data. Why is there a variable feature in SASS if your CSS should follow the DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself) Principle?

Comment: as a side note, CSS has also variable feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your company has a color scheme.  You only use these 4 colors.  Your CSS will have those 4 values everywhere. If you don't use variables then you are susceptible to typos and inconsistencies in design.  If you can simply reference a variable then you can keep it consistent throughout your whole service.

Furthermore, suppose your company rebrands and changes colors.  Sure, you can find and replace in your whole app, or just change the value of the 1 variable.

Comment: oh.  In my opinion its not really needed. You can just give the elements that you want to have a certain color certain classes and just write the property and value pair once.

Comment: @Muhammad a color can be added to border, background, text, outline, etc, etc .. How you will handle all this without variable? you will for sure duplicate some code with CSS